# Translucent white covering my button in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, adaptive-layout

I've set constraints and everything but there's a translucent white "screen" covering the lower part of my screen. It's not fixed to my tableview because when I scroll down the button gets pulled up and is visible but the screen stays there. At first I thought it was a rogue view but it's not so I'm not sure what's going on. Any pointers on what I should be looking at to solve this problem? Here's a picture:
[image]

Here is my code (a little untidy because this is my first project in swift):
    import UIKit

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let manager = WorkoutDataSource()
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    var workouts = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.workouts = manager.getWorkOuts()
        let borderAlpha : CGFloat = 0.7
        let cornerRadius : CGFloat = 5.0


        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
       button.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: borderAlpha).CGColor
        button.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius

        let heightOfVisibleTableViewArea = tableView.bounds.height - topLayoutGuide.length - bottomLayoutGuide.length
        let numberOfRows = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0)

        tableView.rowHeight = heightOfVisibleTableViewArea / CGFloat(numberOfRows)


        let color1 = UIColor(hue: 0.9528, saturation: 0.4, brightness: 1, alpha: 1.0) /* #ff759d */
        let color2 = UIColor(hue: 0.0167, saturation: 0.25, brightness: 0.95, alpha: 1.0) /* #ffb1b1 */
        let color3 = UIColor(hue: 0.2528, saturation: 0.11, brightness: 0.85, alpha: 1.0) /* #f3bbb4 */
        let color4 =  UIColor(hue: 0.3833, saturation: 0.21, brightness: 0.91, alpha: 1.0) /* #cedbc2 */
        let color5 = UIColor(hue: 0.4417, saturation: 0.62, brightness: 0.97, alpha: 1.0) /* #b7eac7 */
        let color6 = UIColor(hue: 0.4528, saturation: 0.91, brightness: 0.81, alpha: 1.0) /* #12d19e */ /* #5ef9c3 */
        //let color7 = UIColor(hue: 0.5833, saturation: 0.7, brightness: 0.68, alpha: 1.0) /* #346fae */
        let color7 = UIColor.flatNavyBlueColorDark()
        gradientLayer.colors = [color1, color2, color3, color4, color5, color6, color7]


         view.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatNavyBlueColorDark()

        setTableViewBackgroundGradient(color7, bottomColor: color1)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatNavyBlueColorDark()!


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return self.workouts.count
    }

    func setTableViewBackgroundGradient(topColor: UIColor, bottomColor: UIColor){

        let gradientBackgroundColors = [topColor.CGColor, bottomColor.CGColor]
        let gradientLocations = [0.0,1.0]

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = gradientBackgroundColors
        gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations

        gradientLayer.frame = tableView.bounds
        let backgroundView = UIView(frame: tableView.bounds)
        backgroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0)
        tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let workout = self.workouts[indexPath.row] as? Workout
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as? WorkoutCell
        cell!.textCellLabel?.text = workout?.title
        cell!.backgroundColor = workout?.color
        cell!.countLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row+1)"
        cell!.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        return cell!
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "detailview"){
            let cell = sender as? WorkoutCell
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell!)
            let nvc = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController
            if let tmp = workouts[indexPath!.row] as? Workout{
                let dvc = nvc?.topViewController as! DetailViewController
                dvc.workout = tmp
            }

        }
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,55,0)
    }



}
```

Comment: Please post code **in your question**, instead of pictures so others and I can help you. :)

Comment: I pasted it above.

Comment: I have a feeling it might have something to do with the storyboard rather than code but I'm not sure what to do because I've tried everything.

Comment: What exactly, is the final result supposed to look like? At a quick skim, your code seems like it would not generate this error.

Comment: Have you tried using the visual debugger to identify the problem view? If you don't know about it, here's [a tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6)

Comment: What is depicted in the picture without this white thing. Everything else looks/works perfectly. I don't know where this "screen" is coming from.

Comment: Check the bottom constraint on the `UITableView` in your `Main.storyboard`. Try clearing and redoing the constraints on your tableView. And do try @RichTolley 's idea, visual debugging can be very helpful in these kinds of situations.

Comment: I used the Reveal app for visual debugging and found out that the view behind my tableview was causing the problem. Thank you for introducing me to the concept, it has made my life x100 easier!!